# ModSecurity SecRule to block a request when it contains a given word in the REQUEST_URI or QUERY_STRING

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, nginx-ingress, mod-security

I created the following `configMap` for my NGINX ingress controller:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  allow-snippet-annotations: "true"
  enable-modsecurity: "true"
  enable-owasp-modsecurity-crs: "true"
  modsecurity-snippet: |-
    SecRuleEngine On
    SecRequestBodyAccess On
    SecAuditLog /dev/stdout
    SecAuditLogFormat JSON
    SecAuditEngine RelevantOnly
    SecRule REQUEST_URI|ARGS|QUERY_STRING "@contains attack" "id:100001,phase:1,t:lowercase,deny,status:403,msg:'Attack Detected'"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: nginx-ingress
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: ingress-basic
  creationTimestamp: "2023-01-20T11:31:53Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: nginx-ingress
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.5.1
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-4.4.2
  name: nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-basic
  resourceVersion: "200257665"
  uid: e6ab9121-9a73-47e3-83ec-6c1fa19072ee
```

I would expect that following SecRule

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI|ARGS|QUERY_STRING "@contains attack" "id:100001,phase:1,t:lowercase,deny,status:403,msg:'Attack Detected'"
```

would block any request containing the word `attack` in the URI or in the querystring, for example in:

https://secrule.sample.com/api?task=attack

But it doesn't. There is clearly something missing in the definition of the configMap of my NGINX ingress controller, but I don't understand what. Any clue? Thanks!

I'd like to use ModSecurity with an NGINX Ingress Controller to block incoming calls that contain a given word in the querystring.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by escaping quotes and double quotes of the SecRule in the configmap as follows:

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI|ARGS|QUERY_STRING \"@contains attack\" \"id:100001,phase:1,t:lowercase,deny,status:403,msg:\'Attack Detected\'\"
```